# Fetch URL from tweet and pass to iframe

Tags: php, url, iframe, twitter

Is there a way to scan a user's twitter feed from a certain hashtag and then pull a URL from within that tweet?

I'd then want to pass that URL to a iframe.

Prefer to do this all within PHP as part of a wordpress install.

Comment: Can you share the code which you already tried in order to reach your goal?

Comment: I haven't started any of the coding yet - I was hoping someone might suggest a plugin or similar to do most of the work.